# How to sniff download information of different pc's on a network(router)

Tags: download, wireshark, sniffing

I am making a Log Analyzer for downloads on a network by different users. So I want to know who downloaded what in the same network (WLAN). How can I sniff this information from other users of the network?

I know SSL packets cannot be sniffed, but I want only downloads that are not secured by SSL.

Comment: WLAN or LAN? Wireless is pretty easy, but if the datas encrypted i think the only information you can detect is the source IP.

Comment: @TardisGuy Its WLAN.But how to get the information of unsecure downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be Wireshark with promiscuous mode as a starting point. 
http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#sec7

Comment: From which protocol i will find downloads by another user.

Comment: Http and ftp. Sometimes https and ftps but can use those to find an actual download just to see that there is traffic.